# Protect XSS issue only by replacing '<' and '>'

Tags: html, security, xss

I would like to know if I can protect my website against XSS attacks by replacing ONLY `<` and `>` by `&lt;` and `&gt;` or am I missing something.

Example :

```
 <?php echo '<div>' . $escaped . '</div>' ?>
```

I already know `htmlspecialchars` PHP function & affiliates

Comment: If printed inside an attribute, `" onmouseover="DO_BAD_THINGS" "`.

Comment: These html attributes are not loaded if it is not betweens tags so... I am wrong ?

Comment: &lt;div onmouseover='do... ' &gt is escaped isnt it ?

Comment: I don't follow, but if you do something like `<a href="<?php echo $_GET['someparam']; ?>"` in PHP or something similar in any other language, filtering `<` and `>` is not enough.

Comment: There are other ways of preforming XSS, it all depends on the context. It's advisable to always properly encode the user submitted data for the context it appears, using the languages feature for doing so.

Comment: Yes i was not very clear .. My content is in a <div> escaped content </div> is it okay ?

Comment: I believe [there are some edge-cases](http://openmya.hacker.jp/hasegawa/security/utf7cs.html) that can get around it. Your safest bet is to use `htmlspecialchars`.

Answer (score 1):

No, for the HTML body you will also need to encode the `&` character to prevent an attacker from potentially escaping the escape.

Check out the [XSS Experimental Minimal Encoding Rules](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Experimental_Minimal_Encoding_Rules):-

> **HTML Body (up to HTML 4.01):**
>
> - HTML Entity encode `< &`
> - specify charset in metatag to avoid UTF7 XSS
>
> **XHTML Body:**
>
> - HTML Entity encode `< & >`
> - limit input to charset http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#charsets

Note that if you want to enter stuff inside of an attribute value, then you need to properly encode all characters with special meaning. The [XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) mentions to encode the following characters:-

> `&`,`<`, `>`, `"`, `'`, `/`

You must also quote the attribute value for the escaping to be effective.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, someone will find his way to exploit it, somehow.

You are underestimating the number of techniques and the creativity of attackers. Read through the OWASP XSS Cheat Sheet https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet to have an idea of the number of ways this could happen. In your case, does it protect against an XSS into an onload attribute? Or into an input that becomes part of a CSS definition? In those situations you already are into an implicit  tag, so you only need JS code to be added, no reason to use '<' or '>'

Do output validation with XSS, it is the simplest thing and it will protect you everywhere, just do it every single time you write anything (no matter if it comes from the user or not) and pay attention to the context (escape/encode for an URL when you are writing a link, escape/encode for JS when you are writing directly into a JS script, escape/encode for CSS when you are writing part of a CSS definition, escape/encode JSON when you write JSON data, escape/encode HTML in any other case).

In addition, even if it is unrelated, I usually point to this site to show how people like to be creative about JS http://www.jsfuck.com/ - this is meant to be obfuscation-only but I used it for evading anti-XSS controls, usually when made by a 3rd party.